# adding data-native-menu false causes the page go back on dialog close

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile page, that opens a dialog.

In the dialog, there is a multiselect menu.

Everything works fine, like

1. I click the button for mulitselect menu in dialog to open the menu,
2. I select the items from mulitselect
3. close multiselect menu
4. and I close the dialog.

Now, when I add `data-native-menu="false"` to the multiselect menu, the dialog behavior changes, like

1. I click the button for mulitselect menu in dialog to open the menu,
2. I select the items from mulitselect
3. close multiselect menu
4. and I close the dialog.
5. Dialog is closed and I see the previous page. Otherwords, I have navigated one page back in history

What is the solution for this?

### Code

This opens the first dialog

```
<a href="#refine-search" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Refine</a>
```

Code for mulitselect menu

```
<div class="ui-block-b">
                    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" multiple="multiple" data-theme="b" data-native-menu="false">
                      <option>Select</option>
                      <?php foreach($cuisines as $cuisine): ?>
                        <?php echo "<option value='{$cuisine->cuisine_id}'>{$cuisine->cuisine_name}</option>" ;?>
                      <?php endforeach; ?>
                   </select>
                </div>
```

Associated js

```
 jQuery('#refinement-done').on('click', function() {  
        console.log('refinement done');
        var options = '<?php echo $search_options; ?>&',
            min_delivery_amt,                 
            is_pure_veg,
            is_open,              
            min_rating,                       
            cuisines;
        min_delivery_amt = $('input[name="min"]').val();
        if(min_delivery_amt && !parseInt(min_delivery_amt, 10)) {
            alert('Min. Delivery Amount must be a number');
            return false;                                                           
        }                               
        jQuery('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');                                       
        if(jQuery('input[name="min"]').val())                                       
            options += 'minprice=' + jQuery('input[name="min"]').val() + '&';

        if(jQuery('#select-choice-1').val())
            options += "cuisine=" + jQuery('#select-choice-1').val().join(',') + '&';            

        options += 'pureveg=' + jQuery('#is_pure_veg').val() + '&';
        if(jQuery('#rating').raty('score')) {
            options += 'minrating=' + jQuery('#rating').raty('score') + '&maxrating=5';          
        }
        console.log('search data');
        console.log(options);
        JE.search_restaurants(options, "<?php echo $service_type; ?>");
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supposedly a [known issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4595) with jQM 1.2. It appears to be caused by a `changeHash: false` option being set on changePage calls.

However, it doesn't look like you're setting this option anywhere, and the default value is `true`. I'm actually having the same issue as you in a project I'm working on right now, I'll let you know if I manage to pinpoint the cause. For the moment, I just reverted to an earlier version of jQM (not the ideal solution, I know).

**Edit:**

JQuery Mobile 1.2 Beta was released today, so I started digging into this issue again to see if it was resolved. It's not. I did, however manage to narrow down the issue a bit, as shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rXRMZ/5/). If I remove the line `$.mobile.changePage.defaults.reloadPage = true;` then everything works fine. Unfortunately, for my app I need this to be set to true to prevent page caching.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It's not solved in 1.2 final either.